# jQuery XML reading / How to make $.fn.find() work case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, find, case-insensitive

I'm trying to read xml with jquery. I get the xml vai ajax request as xml response with jquery.

```
function onSuccess(xml)
{
    this._xmlJqueryElem = $(xml); /* this => main scope (I use $.proxy() here) */
}
```

Then I use `find()` function of jQuery to search nodes and get values as below.

```
var documentName = this._xmlJqueryElem.find('DocumentName').text();
```

This works when the xml response is ***not lowercase***, but sometimes xml responses came from server are lowercase and then it doesnt find any element with key `DocumentName`; because it is now `documentname`.

Is there any way to make find() function work case insensitive?

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample xml or as is returned from the server in both conditions.